# Allow the readonly access in a VOB for all users regardless of the ownership property

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Allow the readonly access in a VOB for all users regardless of the ownership property of the user and the VOB.

Comment: What version of ClearCase are you using? What is the OS of the ClearCase server? What is the OS of the ClearCase clients which will have to access in read-only to those VOBs? Are you using ClearCase Multisite? Will you access it in dynamic or snapshot views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the technote "[About read-only views](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21148961)":

> In ClearCase 4.x and later the `cleartool chview` command is available to change the properties of a view.
> The command offers both the `-readonly` and `-readwrite` (the default) options to switch the access mode to the view private storage. You must be the view owner or the root user on the `view_server` host to use `chview`.

See the [`cleartool chview` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chview.htm).

You can test the current status on your existing view:

```
cleartool lsview -prop -full dynamic_view
```

Note that with UCM, you also have the option described in "[About UCM Modifiable Streams and UCM Read-only Streams](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21315275)"

> Read only streams will never be associated with a branch type.
>
> This means no versions can be created on the stream. No data will ever be delivered to or from the stream, only rebasing is allowed on a read only stream, which is to control the baseline (or versions) that

Comment: Please, the properly thing to do is add the user group as an additional group to the VOB, isn't it?

Comment: @pindare I believe so ,yes. But could you answer the questions I initially posted in my comment to your question?